# Sort RGB Colors Uniformly in Python

Tags: python, image, sorting, colors, rgb

I have a piece of code that finds the most dominant colors in an image and returns them as RGB values. I try to sort them so I can create a gradient image but they don't sort properly.

```
img = Image.open(r'C:\Users\Dora\Projects\Python\Album-Gradient\{}'.format(filename))
palette = dominant_colors(img) #getting dominant rgb values
palette.sort(key=lambda rgb: colorsys.rgb_to_hsb(*rgb))
print(palette) #printing sorted rgb values as a list
#then I convert them into a gradient image
```

Here's the gradient image I get.

[image: As you can see there's dark yellow before black.]

As you can see there's dark yellow before black. The colors don't sort uniformly and there are noise in the gradient.
How can I sort the RGB values so it goes from black to the colors of the rainbow to white, or white to the colors of the rainbow to black?

**(Something like black=>grey=>dark colors=>light colors=>white)**

EDIT1: Here's the link to the full code: [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/dkuflu/Image-to-Gradient)
Also, the gradient always consists of 5 colors if that helps.

Comment: You question looks interesting, but for (try) answering, I need code I can execute... The original image `C:\...\Album-Gradient\filename` is missing, can you please add it? The `dominant_colors` method is missing, can you please add it? Please add the code for creating "gradient image". What do you mean don't sort properly? Do you want to sort the colors from left to right, and top to bottom?

Comment: You cannot sort colours in a sensible way. The problem: colours are 3 dimensional, and a sensible sort (so similar colour should be linear) is 1 dimensional. Note: "spectral colours" are not all hues. Usually we use "pure colours", so spectral colours plus the "line of purples" (which connect blue to red). For such things, you can transform to HSV/HSL. The first value is "hue", so such "pure colour". But orange is near yellow and red. but dark yellow, dark orange (/brown), dark red: should they be near dark, or near hue? You will have a discontinuity

Comment: @Rotem Sure, here's my GitHub repo where I posted the script: [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/dkuflu/Image-to-Gradient) What I mean by "don't sort properly" is that the colors are disconnected. It goes like color-black-color-white. I want them go uniformly such as black-color-white.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi So that means I can't sort by both the colors' darkness and their place in the color spectrum at the same time? The gradient always consists of 5 colors so isn't it possible to do something like black-grey-dark color-light color-white?

Comment: Maybe. Try on a paper (just putting few colour names), and check if you can do it. And probably it will not so bad if some colours are not near other similar (but still in a nice gradient). Google "colour picker" and you may find some inspirations. Or just colour gradient and other inspirations. Just there is no "perfect way", so you should choose according the scope and the user expectation.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi What should I use if I want so sort based on hue and not darkness? As you can see from the picture above darkness might be causing my issue.

Comment: Convert to HSV or HSL, the H is the "value" of hue. Various plot libraries, and all colour libraries have function to convert sRGB to HSL/HSL. Check also standar library in Python: https://docs.python.org/3/library/colorsys.html

Comment: github repo is gone

Answer (score 3):

Sorting them according to their "lightness" value after converting them to HSL solved the problem.

Comment: Please try to share your new code to help others. :)